# Error in DropWizard MIME media not found

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, dropwizard

I am creating a web service which takes a `JSON` Object of a Hotel Management System like name,email,phone etc and extracts it using Java Object.

```
@Path("/get")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AppResource {

    @POST
    public Response setHotel(Hotel hotel) {
        String output = hotel.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
        return Response
                .created(null)
                .build();
    }



}
```

and my Java Object Class is

```
public class Hotel {
    private String hotelName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    private String geoLocation;

    // Must have no-argument constructor
    public Hotel()
    {

    }

    public  Hotel(String hotelName,String email,String phone,String address,String geoLocation) {
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.geoLocation = geoLocation;
    }


    public String getHotelName() {
        return hotelName;
    }
    public void setHotelName(String hotelName) {
        this.hotelName = hotelName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getGeoLocation() {
        return geoLocation;
    }
    public void setGeoLocation(String geoLocation) {
        this.geoLocation = geoLocation;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuffer(" Hotel Name : ").append(this.hotelName)
                .append(" Email : ").append(this.email)
                .append(" Phone : ").append(this.phone).append(" GeoLocation : ")
                .append(this.geoLocation).toString();
    }
```

but when i call this web service so i am getting this error

```
ERROR [2015-08-13 18:17:47,143] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest: A message body reader for Java class com.quinchy.org.Hotel, and Java type class com.quinchy.org.Hotel, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
```

I am Creating request using this

```
Hotel st = new Hotel("Ashish","ashish","9910687844","Delhi","23.32,356");

            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(
                    JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://localhost:8080/get");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                    .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, st);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            System.out.println("Server response .... \n");
            System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation `@JsonSerialize` over your request object, i.e., `Hotel`.
Javadoc [link](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html).